# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property {functionName} of undefined angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, papaparse

this is a function which takes an array as an argument and converts it into JSON (key value) object

```
    csvToJSON(array): any {
    let arr = {};
    let keys = ["companyName", "companyNumber", "companyDescription"];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      arr[keys[i]] = array[i];
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

this is the calling function

```
onSubmit() {
this.papa.parse(this.csvFile, {
  step: function (row) {
    var jsonObj = this.csvToJSON(row.data[0]);
    console.log(jsonObj);
  }
});}
```

I'm using papaparse to read the CSV file to convert it into an array, which then goes to the csvtoJSON function to become a json object. But when I run the function, it shows me the error

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property csvToJSON of undefined"

Edit: using arrow function solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Try using an arrow function: `step: (row) => { ... }`.

Comment: using arrow function worked! thanks

Comment: You are welcome. There is probably an option that you can use to confirm that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using TypeScript, you could use the `arrow function expression`, which preserves the value of `this`.

```js
onSubmit() {
this.papa.parse(this.csvFile, {
  step: (row) => {
    var jsonObj = this.csvToJSON(row.data[0]);
    console.log(jsonObj);
  }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind `csvToJSON` method to an instance of the object instance by `.bind`method in constructor

`this.csvToJSON = this.csvToJSON.bind(this);`

When you using array function then system automatic create `property` that is `bind` to instance but you cannot override property in delivered classes instead of method.